# Restrict pan and zoom in ArcGIS Javascript API?

Tags: arcgis-server, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, web-mapping

I'm creating a web map of a university campus.

I have the map functioning, but I don't want to be able to pan off of the basemap, into whitespace.

Do you know of a function that will auto-pan the extent back to the basemap?

Comment: A later question has a better answer (and jsFiddle) http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66568/restricting-base-map-on-specific-extent-in-arcgis-jsapi-3-3-3-4

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This sample shows one method to monitor the extent and keep the user from panning beyond the established limits.

http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=16956

Comment: Nice find; bookmarked for when I'll eventually need it too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a function to do it for you; you'll have to handle the `onPan(extent, delta)` event from Map, and see if the extent passed in from that event handler that is beyond your desired extents. If it is, you can forcefully set the map extents back. It might lack elegance, though - I haven't tried to see if the effect is a shaky map that's fighting the user.

Comment: I got it working using mcooper's answer, but yes, it does lack elegance. The map is shaky sometimes, but probably just needs some tweaking

Answer (score 0):

My answer to this earlier question has a code example of how to accomplish this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/199366/72254