# Restrict WMSLayer (not map) extent with ArcGIS JavaScript API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, wms, layers, extents

Is there a way to restrict the rendering of a `WMSLayer` to a specified extent without restricting map panning and zooming? That is, I need the client to be able to pan outside the limits of the `WMSLayer`, in which case only the basemap should be displayed.

The WMS Server is external and outside of my control.

I would prefer to find a solution, if possible, that does not hide the `WMSLayer` completely. The users should be able to see the extent limits of the WMS Service.

Answer (score 2):

One idea would be to hide the `WMSLayer` entirely if the map's extent is outside the layers "valid" extent.

Based on [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/66631/26864), one could listen to the map's `extent-change` event and check if the map's current extent is acceptable:

```
map.on("extent-change", function () {
    // Check if map.extent is acceptable, otherwise hide the WMSLayer.
    if ((map.extent.xmin < maxExtent.xmin) ||
        (map.extent.ymin < maxExtent.ymin)  ||
        (map.extent.xmax > maxExtent.xmax) ||
        (map.extent.ymax > maxExtent.ymax)) {
        // Hide the WMSLayer.
    }
}
```

This would not allow the `WMSLayer` to cover the map partially though.

The same idea could be applied using a server proxy as well.